# django-jenkins emits coverage for models only

Tags: python, django, jenkins, django-jenkins

I'm currently using 0.16.2 version of Django-jenkins in my Django application. Django version is 1.6.2

My django application structure looks like:

- my-app

  - src

    - module1

      - models
      - tests
      - helper_modules
      - view1.py
      - view2.py
      - urls_1.py
  - mainapp
  - django-admin.py

When I execute

```
python django-admin.py jenkins module1 --enable-coverage
```

Coverage report is generated, but it only has coverage report for module1.models and nothing else.

I have not set `PROJECT_APPS` variable in settings.py.

Jenkins configuration for django-jenkins looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
   # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_jenkins',
 )

JENKINS_TASKS = (
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_pylint',
)
```

How can I get coverage for everything inside module1?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, yeah, that's bug with models as folder. Try to upgrade to 0.16.3